# Blocking parent form-window in Delphi

Tags: forms, delphi

I'm trying to create a simple application that show two form-windows. The first one, the main form should be able to display a popup form-window when a bottom is clicked. The second form showed must disable the functionality of the main form.

Please show a simple code for this example.

Comment: Please don't close this question. It is perfectly clear what the OP is asking. As is evident by the upvotes and 6 answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
procedure ShowModalForm()
var 
  newForm: TNewForm;
begin
  newForm := TNewForm.Create(nil);
  try
    newForm.ShowModal;
  finally
    newForm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @David: ah ah ah, today we're _meeting_ and you don't feel loved :) You have my great great great respect!!! ;)

Comment: @Marco: See my comment to Shamballa. I won't downvote, but I can't upvote because the code is poorly written. (No variable declaration, needless assignment of `Application` as the owner when the modal form will probably be freed immediately, and no try..finally to make sure it gets freed after use.) Bad example to set for an obvious beginner. :)

Comment: @KenWhite: you're right and I beg your pardon for my poor example. I hope this is better now. Thanks :)

Comment: @KenWhite: I've just red your comment on David's answer: is someone downvoting David on purpose? If so, why? What happened?

Comment: Very close. I've edited it for a minor error (empty param to `Create`, which won't compile). +1. David will have to answer the question you asked (but probably won't).

Answer (score 4):

The very simplest way to achieve this is to show your form modally. Call ShowModal to show the form and the main form will not be disabled and unable to receive any input.

Answer (score 4):

Another way you can create it is like this.

```
procedure TForm1.btnCreateFormClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   YourForm : TYourForm;
begin
  YourForm := TYourForm.Create(nil);
  try
    YourForm.ShowModal;
  finally
    YourForm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I'd upvote this if you do two things: 1) Declare `YourForm` as a local variable (between `procedure` and `begin`), and 2) Change `FreeAndNil` to just `YourForm.Free` - if `YourForm` is a local variable, there's no need to free it, as it goes out of scope and can't be used again elsewhere. If you're showing it modally and freeing it in the same procedure, `nil`ing it is meaningless and clutters the code. :) Also note I'm not downvoting it, but a post showing poor code to an obvious newcomer can't be upvoted either.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some boilerplate code, which demonstrates [*modal window*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) behaviour in Delphi:

```
procedure TMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Result: TModalResult;
begin
  { if Dialog is not in "auto-create forms" list - instantiate it }
  if not Assigned(Dialog) then
    Application.CreateForm(TDialog, Dialog);

  { MODAL forms are blocking input on per application level }
  { so the following call blocks until Dialog form closes }
  Result := Dialog.ShowModal();

  if IsPositiveResult(Result) then
  begin
    { handle if user responds with OK, Yes, etc }
    ShowMessage('Accepted');
  end
  else
  begin
    { or handle Close, Cancel, No, ... }
    ShowMessage('Cancelled');
  end;
end;
```

Distinct dialog results was achieved by assigning [`ModalResult`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/Forms.TCustomForm.ModalResult) property of button *control* in the Object Inspector. For more information read about [`ShowModal`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/Forms.TCustomForm.ShowModal) method.

Here is relevant pieces of DFM code to illustrate ModalResult property setup:

```
  object btnOK: TButton
    Caption = 'OK'
    ModalResult = 1
  end
  object btnCancel: TButton
    Caption = 'Cancel'
    ModalResult = 2
  end
```